# STM32 Shutting down debug session

Tags: uart, stm32, debugging, keil, stm32cubemx

I'm facing with a problem regarding debug session.

When I start debug session, after the configuration of USART2 the debug session is closed.

Keil message:

> Cannot access target. Shutting down debug session

The shutdown occur with this instruction:

```
__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_USART2_ENABLE();
```

This is my configuration:

- STM32F103
- IDE Keil
- Keil project created with STM32Cube MX
- Debug Serial Wire with SWCLK, SWDIO, NRST.

Without debug the board works well, but I need the debug to solve some bug.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your pin settings - you might remap one of those SWD pins required for debugging.

Comment: @TurboJ: The sw pins can't remaped to any other pin (from data sheet)

Comment: The other way around. A SWD pin remapped to different functionality (USART2 in your case).

Comment: @domen: could you explain better? Thanks!

Comment: Most pins can have different functions (e.g. GPIO, UART RX, SWO). It seems very likely that in your case one of SWD pins was changed to USART function which caused SWD to stop working. So check what changes when you configure USART2. It might even be that an UART line that you don't use is the cause (e.g. UART2 RTS shared with SWO, but in setup you or the library changes the pin mapping). You'll have to consult the datasheet, check SWD pins and their possible mappings.

Comment: Problem Solved! Thanks to Misagh92 on STM Forum.

Replace the macro '__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_USART2_ENABLE()' with 'AFIO->MAPR |= AFIO_MAPR_USART2_REMAP | AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG_JTAGDISABLE;' that's remap the UART2 and enable the SW debug. Only one thing to keep it in mind: regenerating the code with ST CubeMx will remove the fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timer1 remap cause debug crash on STM32F103](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260757/timer1-remap-cause-debug-crash-on-stm32f103)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Timer1 remap cause debug crash on STM32F103](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260757/timer1-remap-cause-debug-crash-on-stm32f103). The remapping of USART2 mention in this question, is affected by exactly the same problem as remapping TIM1 in the linked question above - they are just different bits in the same register. STM32 CubeMX code in `__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_USART2_ENABLE()` or `__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE()` or several other macros, tries to do a Read-Modify-Write sequence on that register where the existing state *cannot be read* on STM32F1 family.