# Timer1 remap cause debug crash on STM32F103

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, stm32, timer

I build a Keil project for my STM32F103 MCU with STM32CubeMx.

My goal is use the TIM1 channel 2 for control a Buzzer.
I want to generate a PWM at 4KHz through TIM1 channel 2.
I configured, with STM32CubeMx, the TIM1_Channel2 as "PWM Generator CH2".

The problem regards the debug session. In particular, when I start the debug session and when the MCU executes the macro "__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE()" the debug session crash.

This is the timer initialisation code generated by STM32CubeMx:

```
void HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(htim->Instance==TIM1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 0 */

    /**TIM1 GPIO Configuration   
    PE11     ------> TIM1_CH2
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */
  }

}
```

This issue is related to Timer1 pin full remap.

Anyone have the same issue?

Thanks!

=== UPDATE ===

Finally I found some time to test the solution proposed by @SamGibson an it works! And thanks to @Rafiq Rahman for his code!

Thanks guys for your time!

This is the code that I used to remap the TIM1 and maintain the ability to generate the code with the Stm32CubeMX.

```
if(htim->Instance==TIM1)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 0 */
  #undef __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE
  #define __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE()  (0)
  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 0 */

    /**TIM1 GPIO Configuration    
    PE11     ------> TIM1_CH2 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */
  /* Make a copy of AFIO register */
  volatile uint32_t afioRegisterCopy = AFIO->MAPR;

  /* Clear Timer1 remap bits and + JTAG/SWD bits */
  afioRegisterCopy &= ~((7 << 24) + (3 << 6));

  /* To perform a full remap Timer1, bit 6-7 of 
     AFIO->MAPR must be set. Mask is 3 (11b)    */
  afioRegisterCopy |= (3 << 6);

  /* Apply the new register configuration*/
  AFIO->MAPR = afioRegisterCopy; 
  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> STM32F103 [...] STM32CubeMx [...] when I start the debug session and when the MCU executes the macro "__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE()" the debug session crash.

I don't use the STM32CubeMX HAL, but I can explain the issue and the workaround.

The problem is that the STM32F1 series has one register `AFIO_MAPR` which contains the settings for remapping various peripherals **and** for enabling/disabling the JTAG/SWD connection to your debugger. **And** to make this more complicated, the bits in that register which enable/disable the JTAG/SWD settings (`bits 24-26`) are **write-only** so their existing state **cannot be read**.

See this extract from the [STM32F1 Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190.pdf):

---

[image: Extract from STM32F1 Reference Manual]

---

This means that any attempt to change the settings of the various "peripheral remap" bits, by doing a read-modify-write sequence to this register, could *read* different values instead of the *real* current values in the JTAG/SWD bits. Then, when the *write* to the register is done, your debugger access stops because whatever was read from those JTAG/SWD bits, is written back to them. (Other effects have also been reported, but I won't go into that now).

From what I could find without installing the HAL, the macros used are:

`#define __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE()
    MODIFY_REG(AFIO->MAPR, AFIO_MAPR_TIM1_REMAP, AFIO_MAPR_TIM1_REMAP_FULLREMAP)`

and `MODIFY_REG` is:

`#define MODIFY_REG(REG, CLEARMASK, SETMASK)
    WRITE_REG((REG), (((READ_REG(REG)) & (~(CLEARMASK))) | (SETMASK)))`

So as you see, `MODIFY_REG` is doing a read-modify-write and you don't know what values it will read from JTAG/SWD `bits 24-26` and hence what values it will write back to there! The values read from those bits are "undefined" (to quote ST) and I know I have read different values from the same STM32F1 at different times.

The "fix" I have used with the SPL, is to change any remapping code to specifically set the JTAG/SWD bits which you want, whenever you write to the `AFIO_MAPR` register. You will need to figure out how you want to do the same with the HAL code. One way is to use a temporary variable so, from memory, the sequence becomes:

- Read AFIO_MAPR register into temp variable
- Change desired peripheral remap bits in the temp variable
- Mask out bits 24-26 in the temp variable
- Set bits 24-26 in the temp variable to whatever I wanted (therefore ignoring whatever their, likely incorrect, "read" value was)
- Write temp variable to AFIO_MAPR

Thankfully ST changed to a better register arrangement in later STM32 models (e.g. STM32F4).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Great explanation! Unfortunately my works is changed towards an high priority project. When I solved the problem I switch back to Timer1 Problem. Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working piece of code to illustrate the steps proposed by @SamGibson. It works for me like a charm. First thing to do is to comment out the `__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE();` in stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c and fill in with the remap code as follow:

```
//__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_TIM1_ENABLE();

/* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */

volatile uint32_t map_copy = AFIO->MAPR;

map_copy &= ~((7 << 24) + (3 << 6)); // Clear desired bitfields + debug bits


// 5(101b) shifted left 24 for CoreSight SW-DP (What Keil Ulink2 and St-LinkV2
//use for debugging in either Keil IDE or SW4STM32 IDE)

// The (3 << 6) is me wanting to fully remap the TIM1 AF pins for 
//Complementary PWM Generation

map_copy |= (5 << 24) + (3 << 6);

AFIO->MAPR = map_copy;

/* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */
```

Just be on the lookout for other MspPostInit calls...

Cheers.