# Shared UART on STM32F103x (or any)

Tags: stm32, wireless, programming, microprocessor, stm32f10x

This is one of those beginner questions, so sorry about that.

I'm trying to add wireless chip to my current PCB, but there are no more available UARTs on STM32F103. There is one UART (RX,TX) pins "reserved" for on-chip debugger/programmer.

So my question is: Can I share this UART between the Wifi controller and programmer?

Like disconnect the wifi when I run programmer, and otherwise?

Or can those devices run in the same time?

If so, What it would also take from the software standpoint?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (if I understand your question correctly).

As you did not specify the part number, let's take the 48-pin `STM32F103C8T6` found on the "Blue Pill" boards as an example.

`USART2` and `USART3` are hardwired to `PA2-PA3` and `PB10-PB11`, but `USART1` can be relocated from the default `PA9-PA10` pair to `PB6-PB7`. (Actually `USART2` and `USART3` can be relocated as well, but to pins that don't exist on the 48 bit package.)

Remapping is controlled by the `USART1_REMAP` bits of the `AFIO->MAPR` register.

> Bit 2 **USART1_REMAP**: USART1 remapping
>
> This bit is set and cleared by software. It controls the mapping of USART1 TX and RX alternate functions on the GPIO ports.
>
> 0: No remap (TX/PA9, RX/PA10)
>
> 1: Remap (TX/PB6, RX/PB7)

Of course only one of the connections can be active at any given time, but the switchover can occur any time. The other device will be disconnected, it will not receive any data from the controller, and any data sent to the controller will be lost.

The tricky part is to properly finish the communication with one device before the switchover.

- If you are just sending output to a port, then wait until the `TC` bit in `USART1->SR` is set. Waiting for `TXE` is not enough, as the UART can be still busy transmitting the last byte, which will be lost, or partially transmitted to the wrong device.
- If hardware flow control is possible, you can connect a GPIO pin to the CTS input of the device. Set the pin to 1 to tell the device to stop transmitting, and wait for the time needed to finish sending a complete byte before switchover.
- Otherwise the steps needed to shut down communication depends on the communication protocol. Checkwhether some kind of software flow control is available.

---

There is also a [software UART implementation](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-library-expansion/stsw-stm32156.html) for ST. Although it's for the F4 series, I see no reason why it couln't be ported to F1.

Comment: (+1) Just to add that on STM32F1 MCUs, remapping peripherals in the AFIO_MAPR register can also unexpectedly affect SWD/JTAG debugging, as explained in this question: [Timer1 remap cause debug crash on STM32F103](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/260757/101852)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. So the connection is only 1:1. How exactly are you suggesting to do this software switching? I am worried that I will program the chip to no longer work with the programmer/on-chip-debugger.